# How I can delete words if word have this letters

Tags: php, arrays, string, function, preg-replace

I must delete words if in word have letters **"ц", "щ", "ы", "ь"**. I create this functions for need me but it works slow.

```
public function CheckToInsert($text)
{

 $xarfho = array("ц", "щ", "ы", "ь","қ","ӣ","ғ","ҷ","ҳ","ӯ","Қ","Ӣ","Ғ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Ӯ");

 foreach ($xarfho as $xarf) 
 {
     if (stripos($text,$xarf) !== false) 
     {
         return true;
     }
 }



 return false;

}

public function UnsetUncorrectWords($words)
{
    foreach ($words as $key => $value) 
    {
        if($this->CheckToInsert($value) == false) unset($words[$key]);
        if(strlen($value) < 3) unset($words[$key]);
    }

    return $words;
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to transliterate you can convert the whole string to utf-8

Comment: No, I just want to delete all the words in which there are these letters from the text

Comment: Something like https://ideone.com/1PnQ63?

Comment: Or https://ideone.com/BXMuHv

Comment: It works @WiktorStribiżew and how I can get words with these letters "ц", "щ", "ы", "ь","қ","ӣ","ғ","ҷ","ҳ","ӯ","Қ","Ӣ","Ғ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Ӯ" ?

Comment: Just use these letters to build a `/[...]/u` regex to be used with `preg_grep` and remove the `PREG_GREP_INVERT` flag. Or should the conditions be "joined"? Also, see Casimir's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) to get either the array items that contain a regex match, or those that do not contain a match with a `PREG_GREP_INVERT` flag.

So, to get all the items that have no letters of your choice, use

```
$xarfho = array("ц", "щ", "ы", "ь","қ","ӣ","ғ","ҷ","ҳ","ӯ","Қ","Ӣ","Ғ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Ӯ");
$wrds = array('Еыфвҷ','цӣвееп','аааа');
$pat = '/[' . implode("", $xarfho) . ']/u';
$res = preg_grep($pat, $wrds, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
// => Array (  [2] => аааа )
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/BXMuHv)

To get the items with the `"ц", "щ", "ы", "ь","қ","ӣ","ғ","ҷ","ҳ","ӯ","Қ","Ӣ","Ғ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Ӯ"` letters, use

```
$xarfho = array("ц", "щ", "ы", "ь","қ","ӣ","ғ","ҷ","ҳ","ӯ","Қ","Ӣ","Ғ","Ҷ","Ҳ","Ӯ");
$wrds = array('Еыфвҷ','цӣвееп','аааа');
$pat = '/[' . implode("", $xarfho) . ']/u';
$res = preg_grep($pat, $wrds);
// => Array ( [0] => Еыфвҷ [1] => цӣвееп )
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/IuEKMi).

The regexps will look like `/[цщы]/u` where `[...]` is a *character class* that matches any char (or range of chars) defined in the pattern and the `/u` modifier is required since your pattern contains characters other than ASCII and the UNICODE modifier will make the regex engine correctly parse both the pattern and input strings.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to rewrite your function (or to not use a function at all) like that:

```
public function UnsetUncorrectWords($words)
{
    return preg_grep('~\A[^қӣғҷҳӯҚӢҒҶҲӮ]{3,}\z~u', $words);
}
```

`preg_grep` filters array items that don't match the pattern.

The pattern describes words with at least 3 characters written without the letters қ,ӣ,ғ,ҷ,ҳ,ӯ,Қ,Ӣ,Ғ,Ҷ,Ҳ,Ӯ.

Note that you can't use `strlen` with multibyte characters since this one returns the number of bytes, not the number of characters.

Comment: How i can use this function. Can you write sumple using test code?